# fscanf() reading in data not what expected

Tags: c, scanf

I got my `fscanf()` code which is reading data from a file but not what I was expecting. It should be:

```
A 1 3
B 2 5
```

and so on in terminal

My data file has these on it

```
A 4 7 
B 8 6 
C 4 6 
D 7 3 
E 10 2 
F 3 8 
G 1 10
```

When reading out on terminal I get this...

```
A 4 7 

 4 7 
  8 6 

 8 6 
  4 6 

 4 6 
  7 3 

 7 3 
  10 2 

 10 2 
  3 8 

 3 8 
  1 10 

 1 10
```

I want the data being read on terminal to be the exact format to how it is in my text file. Code below is what I us

```
fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("File, data.txt wasn't read succesfully. \n");
    fclose (fp);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Reading data from data.txt \n");
    //read in data
    while (1)
    {
      dataTest = fscanf(fp, "%c %d %d", &c, &t1, &t2);
      fscanf(fp,"%c", &nl);
      if (dataTest == -1) break;
      printf("%c %d %d \n", c, t1, t2);
    }

    printf("Data read succesfully ! \n");
    fclose (fp);
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to read the newline here `fscanf(fp,"%c", &nl);`?  Maybe there's no newline in your text file.  Also, `if (dataTest == -1) break;` should be right after `dataTest = fscanf(fp, "%c %d %d", &c, &t1, &t2);`.

Comment: Yea, that was reading in carriage return. Wouldn't there be a new line though? The list is going downwards. I'll move the if statement and update on the outcome

Comment: I agree, first if its Windows machine it might even be a Carriage Return (\r), if there is indeed a \n or \r character you can try reading the last value correctly with something like this: dataTest = fscanf(fp, "%c %d %d\n", &c, &t1, &t2), dataTest = fscanf(fp, "%c %d %d\r", &c, &t1, &t2) respectively

Comment: `fprintf` doesn't read data, it writes it -- and you have no `fprintf` calls in your code (though you have several `printf` calls). Can you update your question to make it more consistent?

Comment: the print statement within the loop is for debugging purposes. I was using it to ensure data is succesfully being read by terminal.

Comment: fprintf() is not being used here and fprintf() does not read in anything.  Can you update your question so that it is easier to understand?

Comment: Put a space in front of the `%c` in `" %c %d %d"` in the `fscanf()`.  The space in the format string forces `fscanf()` to skip newlines etc.  You should also not write `-1`; `fscanf()` returns a non-negative number or EOF, and there is no guarantee that EOF is `-1`.  You should check each `fscanf()` call; you should check that the main one gets 3 values.  And with the format string change, the second call, which is supposed to read the newline, becomes redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
  dataTest = fscanf(fp, "%c %d %d", &c, &t1, &t2);
  fscanf(fp,"%c", &nl);
```

To this:

```
  dataTest = fscanf(fp, "%c %d %d\n", &c, &t1, &t2);
```

Or (depending on your file-format) this:

```
  dataTest = fscanf(fp, "%c %d %d\r\n", &c, &t1, &t2);
```

Comment: Do not make that change if a user will be typing the information.  The newline at the end is white space, and the `fscanf()` will not complete until the user types something other than white space -- which requires them to divine what the next input needs to be before the current input finishes.  It is OK in this example where the data comes from a file, but it would be better to do the white space scanning up front: `" %c %d %d"`.

Comment: I just copied this above data into a file and tried it. Seems to be working OK. OP might need to use `\r\n` instead of `\n`, depending on the file format, but the space character at the end of each line does not seem to affect `fscanf`.

Comment: Like I said, in this context, the trailing newline is OK.  The `\r\n` probably works too, on Unix or Windows, when the data comes from a file.  The problem is with input from a terminal.  Then the trailing white space eats up all the white space you type until you type something that isn't white space -- newlines are white space.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said, I'm sorry but I do hate it when this happens #justsaying